# Select rows from a data frame with the same value in a particular row

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have a `.tsv` file, that I imported as a `data.frame:`

```
df = read.table(file.choose(), sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
```

The file is composed of 531 rows and 80 columns. 
From this, I have to extract rows with the same value on the third column.

So, I tried this:

```
cl <- nrow(df)
for (i in 1:cl){
  store<-df[df[i,3]==df[[3]],]
}
```

The code works, it identifies the equal rows, but there is an issue with the loop, because it stores just the last i-th row (plus the equals).
Lastly, how can I store every i-th row (plus the equals) in different variables?
As an example, suppose the file is:

```
  df[1:4,1:4]
  Sample Gene Variant Chr
1 48_S12 AATF GC>GC/G  17
2 48_S12 AATF   G>C/C  17
3 48_S12 AATF   G>G/A  17
4 48_S12 AATF   G>G/A  17
```

In this particular case, my code should store the rows in the same order, but it store only the last 2 rows. In addition, I would like it stores the first 2 rows in 2 different variables, and the last 2 in the same variable (due to equal third column's value).

Comment: Take a look at `?duplicated` - it will be about a bazillion times faster than looping over each row - `df[duplicated(df$Variant) | duplicated(df$Variant, fromLast=TRUE),]` for instance. I'm a little unclear on the output you want in the end though.

Comment: I  probably explained wrong. I just want the code to store the rows with the same value on the third column in different variables. By the way, i'll try `$duplicated` asap.

Comment: I'd really recommend not doing that. Working with "long" data is usually a lot simpler and reduces filesize and code complexity in the long run. Having `Variant1/2/3/...n` variables will just leave you with a bunch of mostly empty columns.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks for the tip, but I used the code provided from kuku because I need that precise output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to store the resulting data frames in one list within which you can access to each of the data frames.

```
require(dplyr)
variant_types <- unique(as.character(df$Variant))

tmp <- list()

for (k in 1:length(variant_types)) {
  tmp[[k]] <- df %>% filter(Variant == variant_types[k])
}
```

The second data frame will be stored in `tmp[[2]]` for example:

```
> tmp
[[1]]
  Sample Gene Variant Chr
1 48_S12 AATF GC>GC/G  17

[[2]]
  Sample Gene Variant Chr
1 48_S12 AATF   G>C/C  17

[[3]]
  Sample Gene Variant Chr
1 48_S12 AATF   G>G/A  17
2 48_S12 AATF   G>G/A  17
```